# Join 1 Table with 2 different table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables in Postgresql. Both these are in different schema. I want the output as in the shared screenshot.

Suppose,for field HDRConfig,if the output value is SE then I want the output as Software Engineering instead of SE. How do I show these with the rest of the columns i.e HDRConfig, AbrConfig & SbrConfig ?

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT l0.Code_Desc AS HDRConfig,
       l1.Code_Desc AS AbrConfig,
       l2.Code_Desc AS SbrConfig
FROM Equipment e
LEFT JOIN Lookup l0
  ON e.HDRConfig = l0."Code"
LEFT JOIN Lookup l1
  ON e.AbrConfig = l1."Code"
LEFT JOIN Lookup l2
   ON e.SbrConfig = l2."Code";
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df3c7/1/0)**</kbd>

```
╔═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║      hdrconfig        ║      abrconfig        ║      sbrconfig       ║
╠═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Software Engineering  ║ Software Engineering  ║ Software Engineering ║
║ (null)                ║ Analog System         ║ Floppy Primary       ║
╚═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

---

Using correletad subqueries(inefficient way):

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT Code_desc FROM Lookup WHERE "Code" = e.HDRConfig) AS HDRConfig,
  (SELECT Code_desc FROM Lookup WHERE "Code" = e.ABRConfig) AS ABRConfig,
  (SELECT Code_desc FROM Lookup WHERE "Code" = e.SbrConfig) AS SbrConfig
FROM Equipment e;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df3c7/3/0)**</kbd>